# When does file_exists() emit an E_WARNING?

Tags: php, warnings, file-exists

I was wondering when does file_exists() return an E_WARNING???

in the manual it says

> Upon failure, an E_WARNING is emitted.

Can you tell me a simple example of this, cause i couldn't come up with anything?

UPDATE:

so, if i try to check a file that doesn't exist like:

```
if (false === file_exists('path/image.png')) {
    //something
}
```

This will only return false, and NOT an E-Warning, right???

I'm srry if this is a stupid question (i'm still a total noob in php :-))

Thx

Answer (score 2):

For example when the safe mode restrictions prevent the script from accessing the filesystem, or the file system is not reachable for another reason or an I/O or permission error occurs.

And I think, thats about it.

Comment: Any authoritative documentation on this answer to be found?  php.net is incredibly vague regarding this.